# How do I bind dropdownlists that are dynamically loaded with Ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a viewmodel:

```
 public class RegistrationViewModel
{
    public RegisterModel RegistrationData { get; set; }
    public List<OccupierApartment> OccupierApartments { get; set; }
    public List<Complex> Complexes { get; set; } // for complexes lookup       
}
```

During registration, the user must select 1 or more Complexes. These values are to be stored in the OccupierApartments list. The available Complexes are being loaded into dropdownlists and then passed in the ViewBag.

```
public PartialViewResult GetApartment()
    {
        var complexes = new SelectList(db.Complexes.ToList(), "ComplexID", "Name", "-- Select --");

        List<SelectListItem> occupierTypes = new List<SelectListItem>();
        occupierTypes.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "Owner", Text = "Owner" });
        occupierTypes.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "Tenant", Text = "Tenant" });

        //load Complex data.
        ViewBag.Complexes = complexes;
        ViewBag.OccupierTypes = occupierTypes;
        return PartialView("_AddApartment");
    }
```

When the user clicks "Add Apartment" in the registration view, the PartialView is added to the table using the Ajax.ActionLink ( see near bottom of the view): Everything is rendering correctly and the dropdownlists are being populated with data, but I don't know how to bind the dropdownlist selected values to the viewmodel.

```
@model PropertyManager_MVC.Areas.Account.ViewModels.RegistrationViewModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Register";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Account creation was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.")
<div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Account Information</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RegistrationData.UserName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RegistrationData.UserName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RegistrationData.UserName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RegistrationData.Email)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RegistrationData.Email)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RegistrationData.Email)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RegistrationData.Password)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.RegistrationData.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RegistrationData.Password)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RegistrationData.ConfirmPassword)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.RegistrationData.ConfirmPassword)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RegistrationData.ConfirmPassword)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RegistrationData.FirstName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RegistrationData.FirstName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RegistrationData.FirstName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RegistrationData.LastName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RegistrationData.LastName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RegistrationData.LastName)
        </div>
        <br />
        <hr />
        <h2>
            Your Apartment(s)</h2>

        <table id="newApartment">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Occupier Type
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Complex
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Apartment No.
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tableBody">
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <br />
        @Ajax.ActionLink("Add Apartment",
                         "GetApartment",
                         new AjaxOptions
                         {
                             UpdateTargetId = "tableBody",
                             HttpMethod = "GET",
                             InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
                         })
        <hr />
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Register" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</div>
}
```

And here is the PartialView

```
@model PropertyManager_MVC.Areas.Account.ViewModels.RegistrationViewModel

<tr class="editorRow">
    <td>@Html.DropDownList("OccupierTypes", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.OccupierTypes, "-- Select --")
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DropDownList("ComplexID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Complexes, "-- Select --")
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBox("ApartmentNo")
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="#" class="deleteRow">Remove</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Come up with a simple repro, don't use your actual code. Start with my working example http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/01/09/cascasding-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the replies. My dropdownlists are populating correctly. My question is to do with binding the selected value to the viewmodel. I thought that the modelbinder would automatically pick up the values in the select boxes but this doesnt seem to be the case.

Comment: Perhaps my viewmodel also needs to hold a list of selected complexes? Dimitri, I checked out that example but I suspect the problem originates in the design of my viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you the [following article](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) for implementing editing of a variable length list. It illustrates the usage of a custom `Html.BeginCollectionItem` helper which which replaces the collection indexes with GUIDs allowing for adding and removing elements without distorting names of the input fields and when the form is submitted the default model binder will be able to properly bind your view model.